# Angular scroll event prevents overflow from scrolling

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, events

I'm pretty new to angular and webdev as a whole and I'm kind of stuck right now. I'm currently trying to do some custom logic with scrolling as I need to move some absolutely positioned elements relative to an overflow's scrollbar.

I have a div:

`<div id="tableWrapper" class="search-table-outter" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
...
</div>`

Formatted with CSS that creates the overflow:

```
.search-table-outter { overflow-x: auto; margin-bottom: 50px; }
```

and in typescript:

```
 onScroll(event) { console.log("SCROLLING"); }
```

When I load up my page and attempt to scroll in that overflow, the event is successfully captured and "SCROLLING" appears in console as expected, however, the overflow no longer scrolls. I'm assuming this is expected behavior however I want the overflow to still scroll while modifying the properties of the other elements. Is there something basic that I'm missing?

How can I capture the event and do what I want while still having the overflow scroll?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create stackblitz

Comment: Does overflow scrolls if this " (scroll)="onScroll($event)"" code is removed?

Comment: @KiraAG Yeah, the overflow will scroll as expected if that line is removed